# django - how to create a preview view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i have an add page to create a new post.and i want to add a link(ahref) to preview the post  at the moment. i have one form and one submit button to save the post into db. i should use the same form to preview. when i click 'preview' link the page must redirect to 'preview.html' which i can display values of form in.

i am stuck. i cannot create the algorhytm for this in my mind. there is one page.one form. one view(addPost) . and i need to reach the values of this form by another view which has another template file.

and i have two fields in models py , called 'titlepreview' and 'bodyPreview'. to see values of form in preview page ; form datas should be written into these two fields.

here models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    body = models.TextField()
    bodyPreview = models.TextField() #preview 
    titlePreview = models.CharField(max_length=100) # preview 
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',unique=True)
    posted = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    isdraft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

here is my add_post view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add_post(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            titleform=form.cleaned_data['title']
            bodyform=form.cleaned_data['body']
            checkform=form.cleaned_data['isdraft']
            owner = request.user
            n = Post(title = titleform, body = bodyform, isdraft=checkform, owner=owner)
            n.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')

    else:
        form=addForm()
        return render(request,'add.html',{'form':form,})
    return render_to_response('add.html',{'form':form,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my  addForm form :

```
class addForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Buraya Başlık Gelecek',}))
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Buraya Metin Gelecek','rows':'25','cols':'90',}))
    isdraft = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    #ispreview = forms.BooleanField(required=False) i just added this line as first step. :)
```

if another code needed ; you can comment below

thank you

Comment: i updated post. added models.py

Comment: is post being saved properly? If yes, simply  redirect user to preview.html and show the data there from db?

Comment: when i click preview link ; it must save the datas to these two preview fields (titlepreview and bodypreview) by using jquery ( no page refresh) and then redirect to preview.html

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `addForm` to a `modelForm`, and then add a submit button to your `add.html` template with the name '_preview' (make sure your other submit button is named '_save'). The code would look something like this:

```
class addForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add_post(request):
    post = None
    template_name = 'add.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
          if '_preview' in request.POST:
              # don't save the post
              post = form.save(commit=False)
              template_name = 'preview.html'
          elif '_save' in request.POST:
              # save the post
              post = form.save()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        form = addForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'form': form, 'post': post}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Your template would have something like this at the bottom:

```
<input type='submit' name='_save' value='Save Post' />
<input type='submit' name='_preview' value='Preview Post' />
```

By doing it this way, you can let the user preview their post without saving it to the database - just make sure that on `preview.html`, you embed the form and include a save button so that they can save the post if they like what they see.

Comment: it does nothing. no error. i just write the code you told. it doesnt save and doesnt preview. :/

Comment: Whoops - I missed the `form = ` line in the `POST` block. Try it again.

Comment: oh forgot to ask..  what about urls? i forget to set urls. i think thatswhy it does nothing. still.

Comment: Whatever you have routed to your `add_post` view should work fine for this as well. Make sure your form is POSTing to ''.

Comment: the second post var looks like gray. unreachable. post=form.save()

Comment: I don't understand you - can you explain differently? As long as you have a submit button named '_save', `post = form.save()` will be called if your form is valid.